# Action on SharePoint New Item form in selenium 2 using C# is not working

Tags: c#, sharepoint, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate sharepoint site new item form but what ever method i try it is showing not found.

I tried `switchTo()` to a new iframe, window...

Tried this code which finds the outer content

```
IWebElement table1 = WebElement.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class=\"s4-wpTopTable\"]"));
int table1count = WebElement.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@class=\"s4-wpTopTable\"]")).Count;
MessageBox.Show(table1count.ToString());
```

above code displays the table count as 2. Going beyond this element does not show any element.

And I am using IE as the browser.

[image: HTML Structure using Firebug]

I used Xpath and could identify till the red mark and it does not identify beyond that.. i am trying to identify the elements marked in green.

```
var iframecount = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html/body/form/div[8]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td
```

Here is the xpath is used taken from FireBug

```
var iframecount = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html/body/form/div[8]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/span/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span/span/input"));
```

Comment: Need **way more** information. What site is this? We will need to see the HTML of the site. What does "going beyond this does not show any element" mean? What does it do? What errors & exceptions do you get? On what line? Wheres the rest of the code that you are executing? Any different in other browsers? What version of Selenium & IE?

Comment: @Arran i have provided the info you asked.

Comment: That XPath is terrible, you should understand the [XPath Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) ...if not, understand it and go from there. As you haven't given us an actual copy of this HTML, I cannot give you any specific XPath to use, thus you need to do it.

Comment: @Arran that xpath is given by FireBug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found answer for this... 
Sharepoint New item form (i.e modal pop up) has 3 iframes without id or name so switching to iframe using the below code works

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(2);
```

i.e frames start from 0 index.